# What does *width:auto mean in CSS?

Tags: css, properties

Can anyone please tell me what does

```
*width:auto;
```

mean in css?

For example:

```
div.ReportingControls dd
{
    width:450px;
    *width:auto;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a CSS hack for IE.
Only IE7 and below will use width auto, instead of 450px;.

[Per Microsoft use conditional comments instead of this kind of hack.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It's a [CSS hack to target Internet Explorer 7 and below](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml). And it's not recommended to use in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is some kind of trick for browser compatibility as explained in [this blog](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Star_Html_Hack)